# autoreconf failed with exit status 1

Tags: shell, autoconf, autoreconf

I am trying to install a program by cloning it with git. I am running in an Ubuntu 14.04.4 LTS. I get the source code correctly with "git clone" but autoreconf fails giving the following error:

```
xray@silvia-desktop:~/Software/Gitsrc/simput$ autoreconf --install --verbose 
autoreconf2.50: Entering directory `.'
autoreconf2.50: configure.ac: not using Gettext
autoreconf2.50: running: aclocal
autoreconf2.50: configure.ac: tracing
autoreconf2.50: configure.ac: adding subdirectory extlib/cfitsio to autoreconf
autoreconf2.50: Entering directory `extlib/cfitsio'
autoreconf2.50: configure.in: not using Gettext
aclocal: warning: autoconf input should be named 'configure.ac', not 'configure.in'
autoreconf2.50: configure.in: tracing
autoreconf2.50: configure.in: not using Libtool
autoreconf2.50: running: /usr/bin/autoconf
configure.in:175: AC_PROG_CPP was called before AC_PROG_CC
autoconf: Undefined macros:
configure.in:11:AC_CONFIG_SRCDIR([fitscore.c])
configure.in:178:  AC_MSG_NOTICE(cfitsio: == Fortran compiler search has been overridden)
configure.in:179:  AC_MSG_NOTICE(cfitsio: == Cfitsio will be built without Fortran wrapper support)
configure.in:186:    AC_MSG_NOTICE(cfitsio: == Adding wrapper support for GNU Fortran by default)
configure.in:226:AC_COMPILE_IFELSE([AC_LANG_PROGRAM([[]], [[void d( int , double) ]])],[PROTO=yes],[PROTO=no])dnl
configure.in:248:    AC_LANG_PUSH([C])
configure.in:249:    AC_COMPILE_IFELSE([AC_LANG_PROGRAM([])],[c_has_option=yes],[c_has_option=no])
configure.in:250:    AC_MSG_RESULT($c_has_option)
configure.in:251:    AC_LANG_POP([])
configure.in:278:                AC_LANG_PUSH([C])
configure.in:279:                AC_COMPILE_IFELSE([AC_LANG_PROGRAM([])],[c_has_option=yes],[c_has_option=no])
configure.in:280:                AC_MSG_RESULT($c_has_option)
configure.in:281:                AC_LANG_POP([])
configure.in:288:        AC_DEFINE(_LARGEFILE_SOURCE)
configure.in:289:        AC_DEFINE(_FILE_OFFSET_BITS,64)
configure.in:304:        AC_DEFINE(_LARGEFILE_SOURCE)
configure.in:305:        AC_DEFINE(_FILE_OFFSET_BITS,64)
configure.in:309:        AC_COMPILE_IFELSE([AC_LANG_PROGRAM([#include <stdio.h>],
configure.in:311:            AC_DEFINE(_LARGEFILE_SOURCE)
configure.in:312:            AC_DEFINE(_FILE_OFFSET_BITS,64)
configure.in:313:            AC_MSG_RESULT(yes)
configure.in:314:        ],[AC_MSG_RESULT(no)])
configure.in:323:        AC_DEFINE(_LARGEFILE_SOURCE)
configure.in:324:        AC_DEFINE(_FILE_OFFSET_BITS,64)
configure.in:454:AC_LINK_IFELSE([AC_LANG_PROGRAM([[#include <unistd.h>
configure.in:458:AC_DEFINE(HAVE_FTRUNCATE)
configure.in:459:AC_MSG_RESULT("yes")
configure.in:460:],[AC_MSG_RESULT("no") ])
configure.in:467:AC_COMPILE_IFELSE([AC_LANG_PROGRAM([[#include <stdlib.h>
configure.in:471:AC_DEFINE(HAVE_LONGLONG)
configure.in:472:AC_MSG_RESULT("yes")
configure.in:473:],[AC_MSG_RESULT("no") ])
configure.in:488:AC_LINK_IFELSE([AC_LANG_PROGRAM([[#include <sys/ipc.h>
configure.in:497:AC_DEFINE(HAVE_SHMEM_SERVICES)
configure.in:499:AC_MSG_RESULT("yes")
configure.in:500:],[AC_MSG_RESULT("no") ])
configure.in:509:AC_COMPILE_IFELSE([AC_LANG_PROGRAM([[#include <sys/fcntl.h>
configure.in:513:AC_DEFINE(HAVE_FLOCK_T)
configure.in:514:AC_MSG_RESULT("yes")
configure.in:515:],[AC_MSG_RESULT("no") ])
configure.in:519:   AC_COMPILE_IFELSE([AC_LANG_PROGRAM([[#include <sys/flock.h>
configure.in:523:   AC_DEFINE(HAVE_FLOCK_T)
configure.in:524:   AC_MSG_RESULT("yes")
configure.in:525:   ],[AC_MSG_RESULT("no") ])
configure.in:534:AC_COMPILE_IFELSE([AC_LANG_PROGRAM([[#include <sys/ipc.h>
configure.in:53:  AC_DEFINE(BUILD_HERA)
configure.in:540:AC_DEFINE(HAVE_UNION_SEMUN)  
configure.in:541:AC_MSG_RESULT("yes")
configure.in:542:],[AC_MSG_RESULT("no") ])
configure.in:552:   AC_DEFINE(HAVE_NET_SERVICES)
configure.in:561:  AC_DEFINE(_REENTRANT)
configure.in:566:AC_CONFIG_FILES([Makefile])
configure.in:568:AC_CONFIG_FILES([cfitsio.pc])
configure.in:572:AC_MSG_RESULT([])
configure.in:573:AC_MSG_RESULT([    Congratulations, Makefile update was successful.])
configure.in:574:AC_MSG_RESULT([    You may want to run \"make\" now.])
configure.in:575:AC_MSG_RESULT([])
configure.in:64:        AC_DEFINE(GSIFTP_FLAVOUR,1,[Define Globus Toolkit architecture])
configure.in:79:        AC_DEFINE(HAVE_GSIFTP,1,[Define if you want Globus Toolkit gsiftp protocol support])
configure.in:93:        AC_DEFINE(HAVE_BZIP2,1,[Define if you want bzip2 read support])
configure.in:98:   AC_DEFINE(HAVE_BZIP2,1,[Define if you want bzip2 read support])
autoreconf2.50: /usr/bin/autoconf failed with exit status: 1
```

I have been searching in this site and others. I found that the problem may be related to an old version of libtool, or to not having it installed, but I have already check this and my libtool package is up to date. I aso have autotools updated.

An interesting point is that I have tryed to install it in a Debian I have installed in other computer in a virtual machine, and I get the same error, so it seems to be something related to an error I am committing maybe in system general configuration...

I have been discussing with a mate thas has no problem in the installation, and get this output when doing outoreconf:

```
lenovo:~/tmp/simput> autoreconf --install --verbose
autoreconf: Entering directory `.'
autoreconf: configure.ac: not using Gettext
autoreconf: running: aclocal
autoreconf: configure.ac: tracing
autoreconf: configure.ac: adding subdirectory extlib/cfitsio to autoreconf
autoreconf: Entering directory `extlib/cfitsio'
autoreconf: configure.in: not using Gettext
aclocal: warning: autoconf input should be named 'configure.ac', not
'configure.in'
autoreconf: configure.in: tracing
```

Any idea?

Thanks a lot!

Comment: What version of `autoreconf` is your mate using? You have version 2.50, the latest version seems to be 2.69. It seems as if the distribution is built using an older version (from ".in should be called .ac"), but it's unclear which. Sometimes, this is mentioned in `configure.{in,ac}` with e.g. `AC_PREREQ([2.69])`.

Comment: When I do `autoconf --version` I get: `autoconf (GNU Autoconf) 2.69
...
---
Autoconf 2.50 chosen by Debian wrapper script.
For information and tuning advice see autoconf(1).`
while in my configure.ac I have `AC_PREREQ([2.59])`
So, this may be the problem... What to do then? I have just upgraded autoconf but the problem remains. Thank you.

Comment: Hmm... I don't understand what that means. You have 2.69, but "2.50 chosen"? Is there some system default that you can change? Also, the error says "`AC_PROG_CPP was called before AC_PROG_CC`". If those two macro invocations occur in the `configure.in` script, you could try swapping them, but that's tinkering and probably unnessecary if you get the versions of the tools right (it obviously worked for _someone_).

Answer (score 0):

Initially, i run the 'autoreconf -i' command on Ubuntu 18.04 and have:

`autoreconf: /usr/bin/autoconf failed with exit status: 1`

But after 'autoreconf -i' i do:

`# ./autogen.sh`

```
Makefile.am:8: error: Libtool library used but 'LIBTOOL' is undefined

Makefile.am:8:   The usual way to define 'LIBTOOL' is to add 'LT_INIT'
Makefile.am:8:   to 'configure.ac' and run 'aclocal' and 'autoconf' again.
Makefile.am:8:   If 'LT_INIT' is in 'configure.ac', make sure
Makefile.am:8:   its definition is in aclocal's search path.
Makefile.am: installing './depcomp'
autoreconf: automake failed with exit status: 1
```

It seems that the error 'autoconf' is resolved and goes to the error 'automake'.